# bulkahead pattern vs Semaphore in Hystrix

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, hystrix

Can you explain me what mean:
"Essentially, there are two basic strategies which Hystrix supports: offload the work somewhere else (using dedicated thread pool) or do the work in the current thread (relying on semaphores). Using dedicated thread pools, also known as the bulkhead pattern, is the right strategy to use in most use cases: the calling thread is unblocked, plus the timeout expectations could be set as well. With semaphores, the current thread are going to be busy till the work is completed, successfully or not (timeouts are claimed to be also supported since 1.4.x release branch but there are certain side effects)."

My questions:

1) Why the timeout expectations could be NOT set as well in semaphore? I think semaphore has method "tryacquire" that Waits for timeout : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#tryAcquire(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

"timeouts are claimed to be also supported since 1.4.x release branch but there are certain side effects" , what's the effects?

2) Using dedicated pool meaning that there is a thread pool for each service?

thanks